# Purpose of assigning objects of subclass to a superclass reference?

Tags: java, class, object

I have always this question burning in me. Why do people assign objects of subclass to a superclass reference as below:

What exactly are the **benefits** and **reasons** that makes people do so?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    A obj1 = new C(); //Why do this ?
    C obj2 = new C(); //When we can simply do this ???
}

class A
{}

class B extends A
{}

class C extends B
{}
```

I understands all the logic where a Class Dog is an Animal but Animals are not essentially Dogs.
I've also bumped into this link: [Why assign a subclass object to a superclass reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254070/why-assign-a-subclass-object-to-a-superclass-reference) which asked similar question as me (but was marked as duplicate with a non-relevant link: [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface))

In here: [Why assign a subclass object to a superclass reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254070/why-assign-a-subclass-object-to-a-superclass-reference) Some vague answers were given as reason for doing so. Unfortunately no more detailed answers could be given before it was marked duplicated with an irrelevant link.

Hopefully someone could look into this question and give a detailed reply on the reason of assigning objects of subclass to a superclass reference.

Comment: do you know what is polymorphism and why is it useful?

Comment: yes.. but if you have some insights, perhaps you could share it in the solution?

Comment: Read abstract classes and their usage...

Comment: By doing `C obj2 = new C();` we also achieved polymorphism? So why doing `A obj2 = new C(); ` ?

Comment: @user3437460 In a large program, you would have some method `checkoutItems(List<A> items) { for (A item : items) item.checkout(); }` (here `A` is a base class) and another method `List<A> loadItemsForCheckout() { /* */ return items; }` These two methods belong to different classes and can be very distant from each other. And the point here is that `checkout()` method won't care how many subclasses `A` has, as long as all of them implement `A#checkout()` meaningfully.

Comment: I don't see how any of those links don't already answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

Classic example. Store list of objects that can draw themselves and draw them when needed.

```
List<Drawable> toDraw = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
// Add objects to draw
toDraw.add(new Circle(0, 0, 10));
toDraw.add(new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20));

// draw them
for (Drawable drawable : toDraw) {
  // each object knows how to draw itself
  drawable.draw();
}
```

If tomorrow someone implement a new drawable (say triangle) this code will still work.

This code is also an example of [Open-Close](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) principle, that says that the code is Open for extension, but Closed for modification. You don't need to change code (modification) that draws all object, but you can still add new drawables (extension).

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell:

```
   Class Pet

   Class Dog extends Pet
   Class Cat extends Pet
   Class Mouse extends Pet
```

you could wrap your Pets in "one" list, by threading them as a pet:

```
 List<Dog> dogs = new LinkedList<Dog>();
 dogs.add(new Cat()) // error.

 List<Pet> pets= new LinkedList<Pet>();
 pets.add(new Cat());  //works
 pets.add(new Dog());  //works
 pets.add(new Mouse());  //works
```

Now, if somebody asks you for your pets, you only have ONE Pet list:

```
 for (Pet p : pets){
    System.out.println(p) //prints dog, mouse and cat.
 }
```

If you keep them at their most concrete type you would need to maintain 3 lists to track your pets.

Note, that a `cat` which is upcasted to a `pet` does not loose it's specific cat-attributes. They are just not available while *seen as a pet* - You can cast it down to a cat again to call `cat.mew()` or `dog.bark()`.

Comment: I agree with you. I did similar experiment before by grouping objects of various subclasses into a list of super class. However, are there other reason people did so? I believe there is? For example: `List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>` instead of  `ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>`

Comment: Because when you declare a variable as `List` other devs can assign  VARIOUS Lists to that variable, picking the implementation that matches BEST (LinkedList for heavy adding, ArrayList for heavy reading) - If you define it as ArrayList, they are stuck to that Type. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist for more differences of the lists.

Comment: wait a minute. you did'nt mention why people use `Animal dog = new Dog();` instead of `Dog dog = new Dog();`? Doing both ways, we can successfully insert into a list of type `Animal`, but why some people use `Animal dog = new Dog();` instead?